# Put quote of modernCV next to picture

Tags: moderncv

I'm using the moderncv style casual and I'd like to have the quote next to the picture on the left, below my name (see image below). I've managed to change the size below the paragraph but not to change the placement of the quote. I would appreciate any ideas on how to do this, thx. [image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\@moderncvstyle}{}
\providecommand{\@moderncvstyleoptions}{}
\xapptocmd{\moderncvstyle}{%
    \renewcommand{\@moderncvstyleoptions}{#1}{}{}
    \renewcommand{\@moderncvstyle}{#2}{}{}
}
\makeatother


\moderncvstyle{casual}

\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.20}

\makeatletter
% new commands to enter the birth of date and the family status:
\newcommand*{\dateofbirth}[1]{\def\@dateofbirth{#1}}
\newcommand*{\family}[1]{\def\@family{#1}}


\moderncvcolor{blue}    

\usepackage[left=1.9cm, right=1.9cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.7cm] 
{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%Personal data
\name{Lydia}{Example} 
\address{xx}{xx} \phone{+xx}
\email{xx}
\photo[70pt][0.4pt]{Lydia}
\quote{{\raggedright\color{dark-gray}{***Quote************************.}}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}

\cventry{xx - xx}{job-title}{name}{city}{country} 
{\textit{description}}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the quote next to the picture underneath my name.
I tried to create it as a second name line, but it did not work.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: It will be nice to provide a MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. I've added the code in the description. I'd like to have the quote next to the picture underneath my name. I tried to create it as a second name line, but it did not work.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Lydia, within the link sam... mentioned to you there's this checklist, which helps you to start with your current CV and rework it to something we'd like to see here, to better help you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 (+ anonymization where needed) . After that plese update your posted code, and perhaps your question. Thank you

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz & MS-SPO I've added more to the code to complete it. Sorry for the mistake. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Is `\quote{\color{dark-gray}***Quote************************.\hfill}` the alignment you are looking for?